# Prevent re-encoding ampersands using Node's setTextContent method

Tags: java, dom, encoding, xhtml, ampersand

## Background

Converting straight quotes into curled quotes and apostrophes within an XHTML document. Given a document with straight quotes (`"` and `'`), some pre-processing is performed to convert the straight quotes to their curled, semantic equivalents (`&ldquo;`, `&rdquo;`, `&lsquo;`, `&rsquo;`, and `&apos;`). Typically, the curled character `’` is used for closing single quotes (`&rsquo;`) *and* apostrophes (`&apos;`), but this loses the *semantic* meaning, which I'd like to keep by using the entity instead---for subsequent translation to TeX (e.g., `\quote{outer \quote{we’re inside quotes} outer}`). Thus:

```
Markdown -> XHTML (straight) -> XHTML (curled) -> TeX
```

The code is using Java's built-in document object model (DOM) classes.

## Problem

Calling `Node`'s [`setTextContent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#setTextContent-java.lang.String-) method will double-encode any ampersand resulting in:

```
&amp;ldquo;I reckon, I&amp;apos;m &amp;apos;bout dat.&amp;rdquo;
&amp;ldquo;Elizabeth Davenport;&amp;rdquo; she said &amp;lsquo;Elizabeth&amp;rsquo; to be dignified, &amp;ldquo;and really my father owns the place.&amp;rdquo;
```

Rather than:

```
&ldquo;I reckon, I&apos;m &apos;bout dat.&rdquo;
&ldquo;Elizabeth Davenport;&rdquo; she said &lsquo;Elizabeth&rsquo; to be dignified, &ldquo;and really my father owns the place.&rdquo;
```

Disabling and enabling by setting the processing instruction didn't seem to work.

## Code

Here's the code to `walk` a tree:

```
  public static void walk(
    final Document document, final String xpath,
    final Consumer<Node> consumer ) {
    assert document != null;
    assert consumer != null;

    try {
      final var expr = lookupXPathExpression( xpath );
      final var nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate( document, NODESET );

      if( nodes != null ) {
        for( int i = 0, len = nodes.getLength(); i < len; i++ ) {
          consumer.accept( nodes.item( i ) );
        }
      }
    } catch( final Exception ex ) {
      clue( ex );
    }
  }
```

Here's the code that replaces the quotes with curled equivalents:

```
walk(
  xhtml,
  "//*[normalize-space( text() ) != '']",
  node -> node.setTextContent( sConverter.apply( node.getTextContent() ) )
);
```

Where `xhtml` is the `Document` and `sConverter` curls quotes.

## Question

How would you instruct the DOM to accept `&apos;` and friends without re-encoding the ampersand?

## Related

Semi-related questions:

- [How to disable/avoid Ampersand-Escaping in Java-XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7469202/59087)
- [Disable automatic ampersand escaping in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58555049/59087)
- [XML DOM setTextContent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20356577/59087)
- [Java XML Parsing: Avoid entity reference resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7240857/59087)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36097922/59087

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the pre-processing to replace straight quotes with Unicode characters, not with invalid XML entities. Those entities are defined by HTML, and is not valid XML.

- `&ldquo;` should be `“` or `\u201C` if written as Java literal
- `&rdquo;` should be `”` or `\u201D` if written as Java literal
- `&lsquo;` should be `‘` or `\u2018` if written as Java literal
- `&rsquo;` should be `’` or `\u2019` if written as Java literal
- `&apos;` should be `'`

Comment: This was my first thought as well, but I believe he wants to attach some semantic meaning to `\u2019`;  meaning, sometimes it represents the start of a nested quotation, and sometimes it’s just an apostrophe.

Comment: Represents the end of a nested quotation, I meant.

Comment: U+2019 is [preferred](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr8/tr8-1.html) for the apostrophe. “U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK is preferred where the character is to represent a punctuation mark, as in "We’ve been here before." In the latter case, U+2019 is also referred to as a punctuation apostrophe.” (The standard would be improved by defining two separate characters, though.)

Comment: @DaveJarvis I'm sorry, I don't see the point of that comment. If you want to use `’` aka `\u2019` aka "right single quotation mark", then do that. The "apostrophe" is `'` aka `\u0027`.

Comment: The statement `&apos; should be '` is a little misleading because, according to the Unicode specification, `'` is not the preferred character. Rather, it's U+2019. Consequently, if the replacement character was coded to spec, it'd be rather difficult to disambiguate on the TeX-side.

Comment: @DaveJarvis Both XML 1.0 and HTML 5 *defines* the `&apos;` [entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML) as `'` aka `U+0027`. There is nothing "preferred" about that, it's a *definition*. If the XHTML document contains `&apos;`, the XML parser should parse that as `'`, unless expansion of entity references is disabled.

Comment: I gave up trying to tease the `&apos;` through and gave up on the idea of allowing TeX to wrap the characters in `\quote{...}`. It _really sucks_ that `\u2019` is used for both curled closing quotes _and_ curled apostrophes.

Comment: @DaveJarvis Agreed.  They are different characters, conceptually, with very different meanings.  Usually Unicode is good about such differentiations…

Answer (score 1):

XML processors are free to treat characters and character entities as interchangeable, so trying to use character entities to indicate semantic meaning is destined to fail.

I would use markup instead.  I suspect custom processing instructions would be a good way to “stealthily” add semantic meaning:

```xml
<text>"She told me, 'Don't forget the bread.'"</text>
```

would get turned into:

```xml
<text><?q?>“She told me, <?q?>‘Don’t forget the bread.<?q?>’<?q?>”</text>
```

Where the `<?q?>` processing instruction is a signal that the following codepoint has semantic meaning as a quotation mark.

Of course, you can have more than one custom processing instruction if you want:

```xml
<text><?quote-start?>“She told me, <?quote-start?>‘Don't forget the bread.<?quote-end?>’<?quote-end?>”</text>
```

For what it’s worth, XHTML [defines its own `<quote>` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-xhtml2-20050527/mod-text.html#edef_text_quote) to handle this exact case.

(Regular HTML [has a `<q>` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-q-element) which is semantically similar, but which also tells browsers to automatically render the quotation marks, which means an HTML document which uses `<q>` must not include quotation marks of its own.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this would be more effort on the TeX side, which was already developed to parse the entities. It's a good idea, though.